# Set-up SSHD to handle multiple key pairs

Tags: authentication, public-key, ssh

I am trying to set up my sshd to accept users that do not have a system user account.
My approach is to use DSA public/private key pairs.

1. I generated a key pair:
   `$ ssh-keygen -t dsa`
2. I copied id_dsa.pub to the server machine where sshd runs.
3. I appended the line from id_dsa.pub to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys of the single existing system user account I will use for every 'external' user.
4. I tried to ssh as the 'external' user into the machine where I set-up the authorized_keys and failed miserably.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: "What am I missing here?" <- Log files and hard data, so someone can actually help you.

Comment: The output of `ssh -vv {remotehost}` from your client will be helpful here.

Comment: As well as the daemon and auth logs on the server…

Answer (score 3):

Probably permissions.

```
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you will only use puclic key authentication, modify the
`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file in the server machine as follows:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
HostbasedAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Restart the sshd daemon and you should be fine.